# Trouble downloading a youtube playlist and converting to mp4 with audio/video

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, youtube

I am having difficulty with a side project I am working on. The goal of the program is to be able to do a few functions with a youtube video or playlist link.

1. download a youtube video and audio and merge them.
2. download a youtube playlist's video and audio and merge them.
3. download a youtube video's audio only.
4. download a youtube playlist's audio only.

My main issues arise with the 2. function, downloading a playlist with video and audio and merging them. The program is able to complete function 1 successfully (download a video and audio and merge to one file), and function 3 successfully (download video and output just audio file) Function 4 hasn't been implemented at all yet.

The program is broken into 2 main files: youtube_downloader.py and main.py
The errors I receive from output of running function 2 are listed after the code below

I am hoping for some clarification on what the errors are describing any advice on implementing the second function outlined in comments below.

main.py

```
from youtube_downloader import download_playlist,input_links,download_video,convert_to_mp3,convert_to_mp4
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
import os


print("Load Complete\n")

print('''
What would you like to do?
(1) Download a YouTube video and audio
(2) Download a YouTube Playlist (video and audio)
(3) Download a YouTube Video's audio only
(4) Download a Youtube Playlist's audio only
(q) Quit
''')

done = False

while done == False:
    #ask user for choice
    choice = input("Choice: ")
    if choice == "1" or choice == "2":
        # Sets Quality Option of video(s)
        quality = input("Please choose a quality (low or 0, medium or 1, high or 2, very high or 3):")
        #download videos manually
        if choice == "1":
            links = input_links()
            print('Download has been started')
            for link in links: 
                filename = download_video(link, quality)
                convert_to_mp4(filename)
                print("Download finished!")
        #download a playlist
        if choice == "2":
            link = input("Enter the link to the playlist: ")
            print("Downloading playlist...")
            filenames = download_playlist(link, quality)
            print("Download finished! Beginning conversion...")
            **#################################################################
            for file in os.listdir('./Downloaded/'):
                convert_to_mp4(filenames)
            #################################################################**
            print("Conversion finished!")
    elif choice == "3":
        links = input_links()
        for link in links:
            print("Downloading...")
            filename = download_video(link, 'low')
            print("Converting...")
            convert_to_mp3(filename)
            os.remove(filename)
    elif choice == "4":
        pass
        #TODO: add option 4 code
    elif choice == "q" or choice == "Q":
        done = True
        print("Goodbye")
    else:
        print("Invalid input!")
```

youtube_downloader.py

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
from pytube.cli import on_progress
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip
import os

"""
Downloads video to a 'Downloaded' folder in the same dir as the program.

"""

def download_video(url, resolution):
    itag = choose_resolution(resolution)
    video = YouTube(url,on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(itag)
    try:
        os.mkdir('./Downloaded/')
    except:
        pass
    stream.download(output_path='./Downloaded/')
    return f'./Downloaded/{stream.default_filename}'

def download_videos(urls, resolution):
    for url in urls:
        download_video(url, resolution)

def download_playlist(url, resolution):
    playlist = Playlist(url)
    download_videos(playlist.video_urls, resolution)

def choose_resolution(resolution):
    if resolution in ["low", "360", "360p","0"]:
        itag = 18
    elif resolution in ["medium", "720", "720p", "hd","1"]:
        itag = 22
    elif resolution in ["high", "1080", "1080p", "fullhd", "full_hd", "full hd","2"]:
        itag = 137
    elif resolution in ["very high", "2160", "2160p", "4K", "4k","3"]:
        itag = 313
    else:
        itag = 18
    return itag


def input_links():
    print("Enter the links of the videos (end by entering 'stop' or 0):")

    links = []
    link = ""

    while link != "0" and link.lower() != "stop":
        link = input("video_url or \"stop\": ")
        links.append(link)
    
    if len(links)==1:
        print("No links were inputed")
        exit()

    links.pop()

    return links

def convert_to_mp3(filename):
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
    clip.audio.write_audiofile(filename[:-3] + "mp3")
    clip.close()

def convert_to_mp4(filename):
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(filename)
    final_clip = video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
    final_clip.write_videofile(filename[:-3] + "mp4")
    final_clip.close()
```

Error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ptcoo\Documents\youtube-downloader-converter\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    convert_to_mp4(filenames)
  File "C:\Users\ptcoo\Documents\youtube-downloader-converter\youtube_downloader.py", line 69, in convert_to_mp4
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ptcoo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ptcoo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ptcoo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 244, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.